# Shell script for iterating over files and directories

Tags: bash, shell

I have a directory containing sub directories labeled by the date. Each of these sub directories contains files labeled by the hour

```
parent_dir\
--2017-07-12\
  -2017-07-12-00 
  -2017-07-12-01
  -2017-07-12-02
  -2017-07-12-03
  ...
  -2017-07-12-23
--2017-07-13\
  -2017-07-13-00 
  -2017-07-13-01
  -2017-07-13-02
  -2017-07-13-03
  ...
  -2017-07-13-23
--2017-07-14
...
```

I want to search for a particular string starting from the most recent files to the least.

I tried the following snippets to iterate over the directories:

```
MAIN_DIR="/<main_dir_location>"
for directory in `$MAIN_DIR/* | sort -r`; do
    echo "$directory"
done
```

or

```
MAIN_DIR="/<main_dir_location>" 
for directory in $("$MAIN_DIR"/* | sort -r); do
    echo "$directory"
done
```

I get an error

```
/<main_dir_location>/2017-07-12: is a directory
```

To me it looks like the shell is trying to execute the directory value obtained from the for each loop.

- Is this understanding correct ?
- How do I remedy this ?
- Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here ?

Comment: I believe you are missing `ls` command, try this: `$(ls "$MAIN_DIR"/* | sort -r)`.

Comment: Have you seen the [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command? That's almost certainly what you want.

Comment: Maybe a good solution is `grep` recursive and sort by the file name.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do

```
for directory in $( ls -d "$MAIN_DIR" | sort -r); do
```

Your command tried to use the directory name as a command.

`ls -d` lists all directories under `$MAIN_DIR` and passed them to `sort -r`

**BUT**

You could just use find and sort the answers by date modiefied (or similar):

```
find $MAIN_DIR -type d -maxdepth 1 -printf "%T+\t%p\n" | sort
```

`-type d` only directories

`-maxdepth 1` go one folder deep

If you want to you can even filter by regex and more complex operations like "newer than file"..

For find options and finds printf options just consult [find's manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)

Comment: What's the cleanest way to iterate over the files in reverse sorted order in the current directory ?

Comment: Try find with type f and pass it the right sort argument. If you find a way to sort the files the way you want using find, you can even use the `-exec` parameter to perform an action on those files. For an example iterating folders see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

`"$MAIN_DIR"/*`
expands (unless the directory's empty) to a list of directories. You're placing this expansion where a command is expected and that's causing the first expanded item to be tried as an executable.

If you prefix the expansion with

```
printf '%s\n' #prints each argument on a line
```

the script will work (as long as you don't have whitespace/globbing characters in the filenames):

```
MAIN_DIR="/<main_dir_location>" 
for directory in $(prinf '%s\n' "$MAIN_DIR"/* | sort -r); do
    echo "$directory"
done
```

If you want to eliminate the issues with globbing characters and most whitespace (newlines would still be a no no), you could do:

```
printf  '%s\n' "$MAIN_DIR"/* | sort -r | while read -r directory; do
     #...
done
```